# Is it sound to use 'state' to indicate an error number to the client?

Tags: t-sql

I'm writing a Transact-SQL stored procedure, and want to be able to report an error back to the client in a nice specific way, without the client having to resort to matching against a string.

I know that a `RETURN` value can be used, but I'm reporting back errors with `RAISERROR` (this also applies to the new `THROW` keyword).  One way is to use an error message ID instead of a string, but this requires the ID to be over 50000, registered in the `sys.messages` catalog, and precludes the stored procedure from returning both an error message string and an ID.

One thing that caught my eye was "state".  Ostensibly this is for determining where in a SP a specific error occurred if the same error is thrown in more than one place, but I see no reason why it shouldn't simply be used for an error message ID.  Should this work fine, or is there a reason I shouldn't use it in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that you shouldn't be using `RaiseError` in your stored procedure.
[The RaiseError documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) starts with this statement:

> Note: The RAISERROR statement does not honor SET XACT_ABORT. New applications should use THROW instead of RAISERROR.

That being said, the short answer to your question is this - as long as you have less than 257 errors you need, you can use the `state` property to distinguish between them, even though that might not be the best course of action.

The longer answer requires some background:

We start by looking at the [`Throw` arguments list:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments)

> *error_number*
>   Is a constant or variable that represents the exception. error_number is `int` and must be greater than or equal to 50000 and less than or equal to 2147483647.
>
> *message*
>   Is an string or variable that describes the exception. message is `nvarchar(2048)`.
>
> *state*
>   Is a constant or variable between 0 and 255 that indicates the state to associate with the message. state is `tinyint`.

Note that further down the page there's a short table specifying the [differences between `RaiseError` and `Throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#differences-between-raiserror-and-throw) - that states that when using `throw`, The error_number parameter does not have to be defined in `sys.messages` (unlike `RaiseError`'s msg_id argument).

Admittedly, this documentation page doesn't say much about the `State` parameter, so let's look at the [documentation page of the `ERROR_STATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-state-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function instead.
It's remarks section starts with the following statement:

> Some error messages can be raised at multiple points in the code for the Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine. For example, an "1105" error can be raised for several different conditions. Each specific condition that raises the error assigns a unique state code.

This basically means that the `State` parameter is actually an identifier designed to distinguish between similar errors that is caused by different conditions.

So, to conclude - I would probably advise against using `state` as an error identifier, and just use `error_number` for that, leaving the option to use `state` as it was designed to be used.

Comment: It's all very well them telling you to use `THROW` but they've removed the string format functionality for some bizarre reason, meaning you need to use 2 lines of code (and a variable declaration) to achieve what you could in 1 line with `RAISERROR`.